# How do I write a query string matching "Client --> Server"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In out ElasticSearch database (version 5.2.2) are stored communication logs with records such as (among others):

```
Client --> Server net.tcp://...

Server <-- Server net.tcp://...

Server --> Client net.tcp://...

Client <-- Server net.tcp://...
```

**Which query string do I have write to match only documents featuring `Client --> Server`?**

The document field with those values is of type "text".

When I write `"Client --> Server"`, it matches both `Client --> Server` and `Client <-- Server`. According to the [query string documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), both `-` and `>` are reserved characters, so I suppose I should escape them, however it also mentions that `<` and `>` can't be escaped at all. So how can I express this query using the query string, if I can't even "say" the character `>`?

Comment: If your field is of type `text`, it'll be hard to match that (i.e. a `keyword` field would be more appropriate). But you can try to use a `match_phrase` query and see if that helps.

Comment: @Val How is keyword appropriate for the bodies of log messages? I though that was the exact kind of data that was not supposed to be keyword.

Comment: Depends ;-) Your use case seems to indicate that you want to run an exact match query on your log body, using `text` won't get you there since the full body will get analyzed and indexed. Have you tried `match_phrase`by any chance?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could add a `keyword` sub-field with a custom [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) made off a `truncate` token filter to only take the first 17 characters (i.e. `Client --> Server`) and then you can do your exact match query on that field easily

Comment: @Val I tried to indicate that the message continues onwards after the first part (sometimes for many thousands of characters, considering SOAP payloads are logged there). I would love to be able to filter these messages in Kibana where all you have is a query string input field.

Comment: See my last comment :-) With that new field you'll also be able to make your query inside kibana easily

Comment: Another way to solve this is to detect the direction when you ingest the logs (Logstash?) and add a new field `inbound: true/false` to your documents.